# Device Compatibility Issues in Play Store

Tags: android, store, playback

I recently developed an app and published it on the Play Store. Some friends reported that they were unable to download it, because that message would appear: **your device is not compatible with this** version.

They informed me of the cell phone models, so I could check it out on the Google Play Console. In the devices tab, I noticed that the models that my friends had were compatible.

Has anyone had a similar problem with this?

```
    <access origin="*" /> 
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" /> 
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" /> 
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" /> 
<preference name="orientation" value="default" /> 

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />

<preference name="android-build-tool" value="ant|gradle" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="28" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Thanks

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle`?

Comment: What is their android version?

Comment: One used a Galaxy S9 Plus and the other Galaxy S10 (both Android 10)

Comment: Is android-maxSdkVersion really need to be specified? Should it be 29 (Android 10)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused by the `android-maxSdkVersion`?

Should it be 29 to support Android 10 devices?

Comment: Apparently that was it. What happens, and I found out now, is that I'm using PhoneGap to convert to APK and it doesn't support Android 10 yet, just Android 9. Soon ... it won't work :(

Comment: Glad that you found your answer :D Case closed?

Comment: Sadly yes hehe. Thanks